# Generate select dropdown based on integer value

Tags: angular, typescript, select

I have a variable inside the component.ts and i want to generate select options based on the integer.

Say i have a variable

total =10;

```
this.totalArray = Array(this.total).fill().map((x,i)=>i);
```

**component.html**

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="#number of totalArray">{{number}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class SampleComponent {
  (...)
}
```

but this gives an error, **`Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call t arget`**

Comment: What code causes this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*ngFor` syntax is `let number of totalArray`. `#number of totalArray` is invalid since about year:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let number of totalArray">{{number}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this.totalArray = Array(this.total).fill().map((x,i)=>i);

Comment: I'm pretty sure the error comes from somewhere else. Your code doesn't contain a `t`. Your `*ngFor` syntax is still invalid though.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what to make from your last comment.
My Plunker link above shows that the code works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144464/discussion-between-face-turn-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: Try to reproduce in Plunker. Perhaps you have the code where it is not supported (perhaps inside the class but outside the constructor or a method)

Comment: actually if i pass some value inside fill(4) ,it works

Comment: `fill` seems to require a `value` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill?v=example (but it also worked without in Plunker)

Comment: I do agree with @GünterZöchbauer. However, it is worth mentioning that .fill, in this case, even without an argument, works. Maybe typescript doesn't like? https://jsfiddle.net/7ockyxmz/ I've never seen .fill used in this way, but for sure the *ngFor loop is not set up correctly, unless you're using a very old angular 2 version (2015?). Also worth noting that .fill(1) gives the same as .fill(). Not sure why, but it may be a temporary workaround if that's the issue.

Comment: JS is quite forgiving. It probably just uses `undefined` as value which is later replaced anyway with `map()`.

Comment: Yes, I've got it. Basically, Array(10) is [undefined x 10]. Then, .fill() creates key->value pairs for the 10 undefined. Finally, .map() converts undefined to the key value. So, literally, using .fill(1) or .fill(129102910450) is really the same, the result will always be an array of 10 elements with values from 0 to 9. Conclusion: the error is somewhere else as already mentioned by @GünterZöchbauer, nothing else to say here but the fact that the ngFor loop is wrong.